# Indent right part of text in ul

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists, indentation

I want to list personal info of a player. However I am having issues with the indentaion, so I used whitespaces, like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Name:</span>&nbsp;Charis Spiropoulos
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Birth:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;10/02/1996
  </li>
</ul>
```

Without the whitespaces, the descriptive text will begin from the : // I googled for its name, but I am getting programming results only :)

I tried using padding, but no luck. Any ideas please? Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/cmfL2643/4/) to play with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use these styles to make the `span`s the same width:

```
li {
  display: table-row;
}

li span {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 1em;   /* padding after the span */
}

li::before {
  content: '\2022';     /* restore the bullet */
  padding-right: 0.5em; /* space after the bullet */
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/msoehed4/1)

Comment: Rick your answer is perfect. However, it seems that I oversimplified my question. The real thing lies here: http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/msoehed4/2/, where you can the problematic output, because I am using an arrow as a bullet. However this is a different question. Do you have any idea on this, or should I ask a new question? :)

Comment: Hell yeah! I am going to upvote an answers of yours I like for that, thanks!

Comment: Damn, in my actual application, the text changes line after BIrth:       Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle?

Comment: I really appreciate your kindness. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/cmfL2643/5/ The problem comes from `display: block;` of `.dashed`.

Comment: Rick you already helped enough. I asked a new question here(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33643639/text-changes-line-on-space). You may want to take a look tomorrow. Tell your wife that you know how to help people! Cheers.

Comment: She let me spend a few more minutes on here. : )  I posted an answer to your other question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94772/discussion-between-gsamaras-and-rick-hitchcock).